# Error reading Parquet file with SparkSQL and HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to read a table from Hive (well, it is Impala) stored in parquet format. I use Spark 1.3.0 and HiveContext.

The schema of the table is:

```
(a,DoubleType)
(b,DoubleType)
(c,IntegerType)
(d,StringType)
(e,DecimalType(18,0))
```

My code is:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
import hc.implicits._
import hc.sql
val df: DataFrame = hc.table(mytable)
```

The trace log error is:

```
16/03/31 11:33:34 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, cloudera-smm-2.desa.taiif.aeat): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.Decimal$DecimalIsFractional$.toDouble(Decimal.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$5.apply(Cast.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$5.apply(Cast.scala:361)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.eval(Cast.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:52)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
...
```

It seems that the Decimal format is not being cast properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that SparkSQL was using its built-in metastore, instead of using the existing metastore in Hive.

You should set this property to **false**:

```
hc.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
```